# How do I query multiple fields into one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that returns each comma-separated value into one column

| TEXT |
| --- |
| A1,A2,A3 |
| X,D3,PP |
| FF |
| DF(a),R |

This is what I have tried.
Below script extracts each comma-separated value (which is never more than 3) into 3 columns and tries to `UNION` THEM

```
SELECT IIf(InStr([A],",")='0',[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1))  FROM Tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT  IIf(InStr([A],",")='0','',Mid([A],InStr([A],",")+'1',Len([A])-InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")='0',[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+'2',[A],","))) FROM Tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT  IIf(InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")='0',[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+'2',[A],",")='0','',Mid([A],InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")='0',[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+'2',[A],",")+1)) FROM Tbl;
```

When running the query I get an error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`
The formulas work correct in the following query

```
SELECT [Tbl].A, 
IIf(InStr([A],",")='0',[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)) AS a, 
IIf(InStr([A],",")='0','',Mid([A],InStr([A],",")+'1',Len([A])-InStr(Len([a])+'2',[A],","))) AS b, 
IIf(InStr(Len([a])+'2',[A],",")='0','',Mid([A],InStr(Len([a])+'2',[A],",")+1)) AS c
FROM Tbl;
```

The desired outcome should be:

| TEXT |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| X |
| D3 |
| PP |
| FF |
| DF(a) |
| R |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are not text, so remove the quotes:

```sql
SELECT IIf(InStr([A],",")=0,[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)) 
FROM Tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT IIf(InStr([A],",")=0,'',Mid([A],InStr([A],",")+1,Len([A])-InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")=0,[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+2,[A],","))) 
FROM Tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT IIf(InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")=0,[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+2,[A],",")=0,'',Mid([A],InStr(Len(IIf(InStr([A],",")=0,[A],Left([A],InStr([A],",")-1)))+2,[A],",")+1)) 
FROM Tbl;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the error persists

Comment: Well, debug your code and values. Both ``Mid` and `InStr` are sensitive to invalid arguments.

Comment: Adding `iif(isnull([A]),"",...` did the trick. Thanks Gustav